# ChaCha20Rng from_entropy() function or associated item not found

Tags: rust, cryptography

I'm experimenting with the random number generators in Rust (I'm a rust beginner) and I can't figure the following problem out:
The rust [rand book](https://rust-random.github.io/book/guide-seeding.html) contains the following code snippet:

```
use rand::prelude::*;
use rand_chacha::ChaCha20Rng;

let rng = ChaCha20Rng::from_entropy();
```

with the note that the `getrandom` feature needs to be enabled on the crate `rand_core` (which I'm doing: `rand_core = { version = "0.5", features = ["getrandom"] }`). I get the following error however: `no function or associated item named 'from_entropy' found for struct 'rand_chacha::ChaCha20Rng' in the current scope`. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction about how I can get this piece of code to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trait method `SeedableRng::from_entropy` was added in `rand_core` version 0.6 and does not exist in `rand_core` version 0.5.

You will need to change your `Cargo.toml`'s `[dependencies]` section to request:

- `rand_core` version 0.6 or later, and also
- `rand_chacha` version 0.3 or later, so that the dependency from `rand_chacha` to `rand_core` matches that version, because Cargo considers 0.6.* to be incompatible with 0.5.*.

Comment: Aaah I see thank you for pointing this out! It was already a little late for me it seems like....